# Equal Height Responsive Search Form

Tags: css, less

I need an inline equal height search form that looks the same in all browsers.

http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/BcIFm

At the moment I have the following HTML markup:

```
<form method="get" action="#">
  <input type="search"/><input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

And the following CSS (LESS):

```
form {

  box-sizing: border-box; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 20px 116px 20px 0;

  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40%;

  input {

    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    &[type="search"] {
      background-color: aqua;
      border: 1px solid aqua;
      font-size: 24px;
      padding: 8px;
      width: 100%;     
    }

    &[type="submit"] {
      background-color: #404040;
      border: 1px solid #404040;      
      color: white;
      font-size: 24px;
      padding: 8px;      
      width: 100px;
    }

    &:-moz-focus-inner {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }    

  } // input

} // form
```

**THE PROBLEMS:**

**FIREFOX:** The button seems to have one extra pixel on top and bottom;

**IE 9, IE10:** There is a padding on the right. No idea why ...

**CHROME:** The same as in IE 10 - There is a padding on the right.

**SAFARI:** Even worse. The Submit Input is higher then the Search Input.
            And there is a right padding just as in IE 10 and Chrome.

**All solved when using Normalize.css**
Using overflow: hidden on the form also seems to better align the borders.

Could someone, please, help me out in improving this form and solving the problems?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Try including 'Reset.css' or 'Normalize.css' in the css settings for codepen. Normalize is more recent and my preference

Comment: I usually use normalize and it seems it solves 3 of the 4 browser problems. I keep having a right padding on Googlr Chrome. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The padding issues you are having all stem from the way you have constructed the form div with a large right padding.

One idea would be to get rid of that right padding, and change the 'search' and 'submit' inputs so their widths equal 100% instead of both being 100%. If they were 80% and 20% for example you shouldnt need the large right padding on form. Then you can just set a margin around them or something to add space between them and the red line.

Comment: By using 80% and 20% wouldn't I get a really large button on big screens? Note that the width of the button is fixed to 100px ...

Comment: I do not want space between the inputs and the red line ... I would like to look as in Firefox but without the extra pixel on top and bottom

Comment: ah my mistake, but if you wanted it responsive dont you want the button to be percentage as well? So that it all scales accurately.
Either way the large padding-right on the form is whats causing the issues.

Comment: But then in a large screen i might have a really wide button which looks bad and in mobile i might end up with a very small button ... if the screen width varies, for example, between 320px and 1400px it might be to much ... Maybe using media queries to have width percentages ... but i was trying other solutions. BTW, by using normalize i ended up only with the Chrome problem ... Any idea why?